# How to create a spike and slab prior plot in R?

Tags: bayesian, prior

I was reading a paper and came across a nice plot of a spike and slab prior from page three of [EMVS: The EM Approach to Bayesian Variable Selection](https://homes.stat.unipd.it/sites/homes.stat.unipd.it.lauraventura/files/EMVS%20Padua%203-22-13.pdf)

[image]

It appears that the spike and slab is a bit different than what is traditionally in literature. I was wondering if anyone knew how I can create such a plot in R. Would I need to use grid sampling to create such a plot? It seems due to the niceness of the plot that they used a closed-form. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into `BoomSpikeSlab`? It's an `R` package for Spike-and-Slab stuff.  I'm trying to do something similar in Python.